# Soar To Their...Gain

Tags: grammar, meaning, usage

I have some question about the pattern "soar to something" [here](http://www.firstenercastfinancial.com/news/story/60394-natural-gas-futures-surge-cold-weather):

> Natural gas prices on Monday ***soared to their biggest one-day gain*** in nearly nine months, as traders and investors braced for below-normal temperatures that are expected to stoke demand for the heating fuel.

I was thinking that when prices increase, they increase to new prices. So, prices should "*soar*" to new higher prices, not to a *gain*.  "Gain" is the magnitude of the price increase.  Prices could soar ***by*** some magnitude, but not ***to*** a magnitude.  So, "*soared* ***to*** *their biggest one-day gain*" seems off to me.

Would "*soared* ***by*** *their biggest one-day gain*" be better?

Comment: What leads you to believe that prices should not "soar to" their largest one-day gain in nine months?

Comment: Why do you many times think that something written by a native English speaker is wrong? :) Do you know what **gain** means? If so, I echo @ColleenV 's question to you?

Comment: @CarSmack  "*Gain*" is the magnitude of the price increase.  I was thinking when prices increase, they increase to new prices.  Prices could soar ***by*** some magnitude, but not ***to*** a magnitude.

Comment: @ColleenV  "*Gain*" is the magnitude of the price increase.  I was thinking when prices increase, they increase to new prices.  Prices could soar ***by*** some magnitude, but not ***to*** a magnitude.

Comment: Your explanation of your thinking helps us understand the source of your confusion - it would be great if you included it in your question.

Comment: I am a native English speaker, and an engineer, and  I  would avoid this construction.  It is common enough that I can't quite say it is "wrong," but it is potentially misleading.  I would opt for something like: _Natural gas prices on Monday soared **in** their biggest one-day gain in nearly nine months._

Comment: @ColleenV  So, the example was poorly written?

Answer (score 1):

> Natural gas prices on Monday soared to their biggest one-day gain in nearly nine months ...

I believe you're parsing it as something like *soaring to [a destination]*, when really, the meaning of the clause is probably something more like:

> Natural gas prices on Monday soared (to achieve their biggest one-day gain in nearly nine months)...

Comment: Would "*soared* ***by*** *their biggest one-day gain*" be better?

Comment: No. That's infelicitous as it means it soared (and passed near) their biggest one-day gain.

Comment: I prefer “soared[,] **for** … gain”.

Answer (score 0):

'Soared to' is implying that the prices have reached a new height or milestone.

'Soared by' says that the prices have increased by an amount.